# PHP html entities superscript 2 prints K in square

Tags: php, superscript

**Browser**
Google Chrome

**Problem**
 
When printing a string with PHP containing a superscript like " **²** ", it shows a K in a square like this:

[screenshot K in square](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3A74b.png)

**Not working solutions and active settings**

- I allready tried solving it with htmlentities(), but nothing changes.
- meta charset="UTF-8" is set
- header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8') is set

How do I fix this?

Comment: my best guess is that the problem is in the html or css of the page you're printing it on. try a plain page with nothing but `<?php echo htmlentitites('²');` , what do you get?

Comment: I get the right result 
&sup2; what are the problems I have to look for?

Comment: if that worked, then remove random <style> tags from the page where it doesn't work until it starts working, it's probably some CSS rules somewhere